# Scaling all elements on a webpage through CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried a lot of solutions suggested on here for scaling a variety of elements on a webpage - without luck. :-(

I have 4 elements (a background and 3 buttons) that I need to scale relative to window size but they need to stay in the same relation to each other. So if the window gets smaller, they all become smaller and retain their inter-relative position.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you shoud use css for buttons and give them fixed width in desktop upon resizing or samller viewport, use media query to make there width inherit so they will be 100% to view port this way they will retain their inner position as you asked. if you really want to use images then try 
background-size: 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is no hard, instead of using px, you should use % instead. Since I haven't earned enough 50 reputations, I have to write it here instead of writing it as a comment

Comment: if you use %, when you resize background, buttons will also resize

Comment: but if you use px, the width and length of button is fixed

Comment: Can you explain this more in-depth? I only use px for margins - is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh! I got it now. Just use margins with %. Thanks man, in the end I just put the background image as a background image and used margin-left and margin-top with % and it works like a charm now.